# JMETER - run next HTTP request after first iteration is finished

Tags: jmeter, csv-file

I have one HTTP request, .csv file with 50 different inputs, 50 rows in .csv

I would like to start next iteration of HTTP request only after first one is finished.

I could use ramp up period, but i cannot be sure that next iteration will start when first one is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory to run 50 threads, to read 50 rows from .csv as some tutorials would suggest

All user has to do is to run 1 user and to set loop counter in thread group

Comment: I'm confused, sevdah - is this an attempt to answer your own question? I mean, answering your own question (essentially knowledge sharing) is perfectly fine!! But I'll be honest with you: I don't understand your question, and your answer is even more confusing. Could you clarify what it is you're asking, and what this answer does to answer that question? Thanks!!

Comment: I agree with you. Question is confusing and i would say it is basic level of JMeter. I was studying how to run jmeter using parameters from input file. In most of the tutorials, i have read that if you have 50 different inputs(50 rows in .csv), you have to set 50 threads and this is not true. If user set 1 thread and infinite loop, every new iteration will take new input until EOF and then start over. thanks